# Division isn't associative

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Consider the following fraction:

$$\frac{\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{c}}{a}$$

How to explain that:

$$\frac{\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{c}}{a} \ne \frac{\frac{a^2}{b}}{c}$$

Obviously, you get different results. But a-priori, one might think that $a:b:c:d$ is associative. Is there any good way proving/explaining the difference, other then **showing** the different results?

Thanks.

Comment: This would be easier to understand if you wrote $(a\div (b\div c))\div d $ (or whatever) instead of stacking up the fractions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That example is a bit more complex that you need to show that associativity fails. You only need one counterexample:
$$ 2 \div (1\div 2) = 4 \ne 1 = (2\div 1)\div 2 $$

More intuitively (?), division is not associative, because if you look at one of the operands to a nest of divisions, the result will vary either in proportion to it or inversely to it depending on whether it's to the *right* of an *odd* or *even* number of divisions. And the basic associative law changes the number of operations the rightmost operand is to the right of by 1.